# Obtener valor de registro checkbox en controller MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una vista MVC C# en la que muestro los registros de empleados de una región especifica, ademas he agregado un checkbox para que el usuario pueda seleccionar uno o varios empleados con los cuales trabajare luego.

este es el modelo que utilizo en la vista MVC

```
public class Developer
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string areaDev { get; set; }
        public string nameDev { get; set; }
        public string expDev { get; set; }
        public string langDev { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

este es el controller desde donde recupero la información de los empleados que muestro en la vista

```
 public ActionResult DeveloperView() {
            string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            List<WebApplication1.Models.Developer> Records = new List<Models.Developer>();
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection();
            sql.ConnectionString = conexion;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Developer";
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Models.Developer data = new Models.Developer();
                    data.code = Convert.ToInt32(dr["code"]);
                    data.areaDev = dr["areaDev"].ToString();
                    data.nameDev = dr["nameDev"].ToString();
                    data.expDev = dr["expDev"].ToString();
                    data.langDev = dr["langDev"].ToString();
                    data.isChecked = false;
                    Records.Add(data);
                }
            }
            return View(Records);
        }
```

y esta es la vista en la que muestro la informacion

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Developer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeveloperView";
}

<h2>DeveloperView</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using(Html.BeginForm("ShowRecords","Home"))
{

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.code)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.areaDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nameDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.expDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.langDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isChecked)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.areaDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nameDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.expDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.langDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.isChecked)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al presionar el boton submit no recibo ninguna informacion en el controller ShowRecords, recibo NULL 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el controller

```
 public ActionResult ShowRecords(List<WebApplication1.Models.Developer> datos)
        {
            List<WebApplication1.Models.Developer> lista = new List<Models.Developer>();
            foreach(var item in datos)  
            {  
                if(item.isChecked)  
                {
                    WebApplication1.Models.Developer data = new WebApplication1.Models.Developer();
                    data.code = item.code;
                    data.nameDev = item.nameDev;
                    data.areaDev = item.areaDev;
                    data.expDev = item.expDev;                   
                    data.langDev = item.langDev;
                    lista.Add(data);
                }            
            }  

            return View(lista); 
        }
```

Como podría obtener los valores de los registro cuyo checkbox se ha seleccionado?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que cambiar tu vista a :

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Developer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeveloperView";
}

<h2>DeveloperView</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using(Html.BeginForm("ShowRecords","Home"))
{

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.code)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.areaDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nameDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.expDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.langDev)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isChecked)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@for(var i = 0; i< Model.Count; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> Model[i].code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> Model[i].areaDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> Model[i].nameDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> Model[i].expDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].langDev)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> Model[i].isChecked)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

tratas de enviar información por medio del botón de tipo `submit` pero no tienes un formulario, el cual debe apuntar hacia una acción, en este caso tu método `ShowRecords`.

Una solución que podría darte es usar Jquery para poder recorrer tu tabla y verificar que filas tienen el check seleccionado. Vas generando un array de objetos con la información de la fila.

Hecho esto realizarías un `$.get()` o `$.ajax()`, pasando los datos respectivos, para poder enviar la petición hacia el método que desees.

Puedes hacer algo como por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Controller/ShowRecords',
        data: [], //Arreglo de los objetos seleccionados
        success: function (response) {          
            // Lógica que desees que haga
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            // Error
        }
    });
```

O también podrías enviar todas las filas y como lo haces en tu acción verificar que objetos tienen el campo `isChecked` en `true`.

Comment: Sería bueno que revises la extensión `Html.BeginForm`